# If a generic type variable is used as a field in a class, should it include the <T> expression?

Tags: java, list, generics

I have a generic type Node:

```
public class Node<T> {

    private T element;
    private Node<T> next;

    public T getElem() {
        return element;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setElem(T newElem) {
        element = newElem;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> n) {
        next = n;
    }
}
```

And I used it as a field in the class DynamicList:

```
public class DynamicList<T> implements MyList<T>{
    private Node<T> head;
}
```

I found that when I used

```
private Node head;
```

It won't affect the list behaviors. So which one is right?

Comment: By the same reasoning, you might as well use `List` everywhere instead of `List<Something>`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seriously it will not effect the behavior, because the types are erased at runtime. But if you do not specifiy a generic type argument, there is no type check and this can lead you to programming mistakes. So the first one is the better solution. If you are using a compiler with the right configurations, it should tell you that you are using the Raw type when writing `private Node head;`.

Answer (score 1):

The first is case is that the *generic type check*

And in your second case

private Node head;

That means here your are using [**`Raw type`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) which is equivalent to

```
private Node<Object> head;
```

Where `Object` is `T` now.

The Java compiler erases all type parameters and replaces each with its first bound if the type parameter is bounded, or Object if the type parameter is unbounded.

You should avoid using raw types. Codes using Raw types are *unsafe code to runtime*

Answer (score 1):

Using `Node<T>` you ensure that `DynamicList` can no accept nodes with other data Type for `Node.element`. Other way, there is no restriction.